# CoffeeScript: Expand array in function call

Tags: coffeescript, splat

In Ruby I can call methods with array elements used as positional parameters like this

```
method(fixed_arg1, fixed_arg2, *array_of_additional_args)
```

Here the "*" operator expands the array in place.

I'm trying to do the same in CoffeeScript, but haven't found a way. Specifically, I want to pass additional arguments in a call to a jQuery function

```
$('#my-element').toggle(true, *config.toggleOptions)
```

The syntax above does not work, obviously, and I'm looking for a way that does.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try

```
$('#my-element').toggle(true, config.toggleOptions...)
```

Comment: Thanks. Now that you show that example, it seems kind of obvious, but it wasn't before I knew it.

Answer (score 2):

You need to [splat](http://coffeescript.org/#splats) it.

```
fun(1,2,3,4,5)

fun = (first, second, rest...) ->
alert first # 1
alert second # 2
alert rest   # [3, 4, 5 ]
```