# Passing array as argument fails in JavaScript in an odd situation

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

I want to be able to take an array from another method call, and tack on an additional argument when I pass it to another function. Having read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10960374/coffeescript-expand-array-in-function-call), I made the following CoffeeScript:

```
class TestMe
  some_meth: (four) ->
    (console.log e) for e in four

foo= [37.5,5,255.0]
t= new TestMe()
t.some_meth(foo...,1)
```

It compiles into the following JavaScript (coffee version 1.9.1):

```
(function() {
  var TestMe, foo, t,
    slice = [].slice;
  TestMe = (function() {
    function TestMe() {}
    TestMe.prototype.some_meth = function(four) {
      var e, i, len, results;
      results = [];
      for (i = 0, len = four.length; i < len; i++) {
        e = four[i];
        results.push(console.log(e));
      }
      return results;
    };
    return TestMe;
  })();
  foo = [37.5, 5, 255.0];
  t = new TestMe();
  t.some_meth.apply(t, slice.call(foo).concat([1]));
}).call(this);
```

This produces no output.

Stepping through in the debugger (`node debug`), I discovered that the argument to the function is just the first element of the array (and not as an array). Which is odd, because if I execute `slice.call(foo).concat([1])` in the debugger, I get an array as the output. If I change the signature of `some_meth` to accept four arguments, the output is as expected.

Obviously, there are several work-arounds available to me, and I'll use one of them, but I certainly prefer the clarity and simplicity of being able to write `t.some_meth(foo...,1)`.

Does anyone have any insight into why this idiom fails to work as expected? What would be the idiomatic way to accomplish the goal of being able to pass an array of four elements, where one element is constant, and the remainder come from another array?

Comment: `results.push(console.log(e))` is going to be a whole bunch of undefined, as `console.log` doesn't return anything. It looks like you're mapping the input list rather than simply iterating over it.

Comment: If you just want to pass an array, please pass an array and don't expand it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your bug is in `t.some_meth(foo...,1)`.  You are passing the content of an array of numbers `[37.5, 5, 255.0, 1]` as arguments to `t.some_meth`.  Thus the `ìn` fails as four is not an array but the number `37.5`.

The correct call would be:

```
t.some_meth [foo..., 1]
```

thus passing in the array.

Comment: @mu you're right: my answer was unclear.  I've edited to make it clearer (I hope).

Comment: Thanks. I'm not quite sure how I missed that, given how obvious it is in hindsight!